# How to get media file's ID from kentico's media selection?

Tags: c#, kentico

I am creating a custom web part for my project, so I need to select files (.pdf, ,doc, etc...) from a media library. I am using kentico's media selection form control and getting the value on my code behind like this:

```
public string DocumentInfo 
{ 
   get 
   { 
     return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("MediaInfo"), "") 
   }
}
```

Doing this I am getting the path of my file (e.g ~/BlankSite/media/Office/test-file.pdf?ext=.pdf) but what I need is the ID, so I can get the Media Info with Kentico's MediaFileInfoProvider, for example:

```
MediaFileInfo info = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo(int mediaFileID);
```

The real question, is how can I get the ID from the media selection and use it in the previous provider? Or how can I get the Media Info from my file with an other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `MediaFileInfoProvider info = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo(string siteName, string mediaFilePath, string libraryFolder);`?

So you might call:

```
MediaFileInfoProvider info = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo(CurrentSite.SiteName, "~/BlankSite/media/Office/test-file.pdf?ext=.pdf", null);
```

Comment: Thanks mnield!! It works!!... I just had to remove all the info before my document name and remove the query params to get `test-file.pdf`.