# Kentico 12 (Portal) - Retrieve Media File Info from Media Selection in code behind

Tags: c#, kentico

I'm creating a widget that would allow a user to select an image from the media library using the Media Selector control, and return both the image and the file's attributes (Title, alt text, etc).

I'm attempting to use the [MediaFileInfoProvider method](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_2/api/html/M_CMS_MediaLibrary_MediaFileInfoProvider_GetMediaFileInfo_3.htm) by providing the Site name, File Path, and Library folder, but I can't get it to return anything. I also can't find any documentation on this method for Kentico 12 - so I'm going based on what I could find for 8.2.

**File Path Provided:** `/NAIT/media/nait-ca-content/about/0I3A6642_060519_Inst_Excellence_Nominees_2.jpg?ext=.jpg`

**Code:**

```
MediaFileInfo mediaInfo1 = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo("NAIT", "about/0I3A6642_060519_Inst_Excellence_Nominees_2.jpg", "nait-ca-content");

string strFileTitle = mediaInfo1["FileTitle"].ToString();
```

There's no error using this code, nothing in the event log, but nothing returned either. I've tried a number of different ways to format the File Path, including the ones suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637570/how-to-get-media-files-id-from-kenticos-media-selection) - so far none have worked.

Does anyone know if this method is still supported in Kentico 12? Or if there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

By saying that you want to create an widget I assume that you are using Kentico 12 MVC. You can use the '[MediaFilesSelector](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/developing-websites/page-builder-development/page-and-media-selectors-for-page-builder-components#Pageandmediaselectorsforpagebuildercomponents-Mediafilesselector)' by adding the following property in your widget properties.

```
[EditingComponent(MediaFilesSelector.IDENTIFIER, Label = "Image", Order = 1)]
public IList<MediaFilesSelectorItem> Image { get; set; }
```

In your widget controller you can then use this to retrieve the media file GUID.

```
var fileGuid = GetProperties().Image?.FirstOrDefault()?.FileGuid ?? Guid.Empty
```

Then you can get the media file info by using the following code:

```
var mediaFile = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo(fileGuid, SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);
```

Comment: Sorry - I should have specified. No, unfortunately we're on Kentico 12 Portal. I'll edit my question to add that.